# Error in polyfill.ts when upgrading to Angular 4.4.4 from 4.3.6

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I recently updated angular to 4.4.4 and when i try to build with angular-cli i get the following error message:

[image: error in console]

I have located that the build error show when i add this line to the polyfill.ts file:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

From what I can see there is no dist folder for the zone.js folder in node_modules folder but that's as far as I have gotten with this issue.

Comment: rerun npm install

Comment: doh...thought i did but needed to delete node_modules first. Thanks!